# Is there any way to run custom commands with go install command?

Tags: go, go-templates

I've written a simple code generation tool. I've used text/template package in this tool. When I installed it with `go build` command, it installed successfully. The only problem I'm facing is how to install templates when you install the program. Currently It is unable to get templates.

Shall I use template text in .go files or Is there any other way we can give instructions to install binary and templates at a particular location? I think it's good to have template text in between code as a raw string. But is there any particular way to doing the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [embed](https://golang.google.cn/pkg/embed/) package.

> Package embed provides access to files embedded in the running Go program.
>
> Go source files that import "embed" can use the //go:embed directive to initialize a variable of type string, []byte, or FS with the contents of files read from the package directory or subdirectories at compile time.

```golang
import (
    "embed"
    "text/template"
)

//go:embed templates/*
var mytemplateFS embed.FS

func main() {
    t := template.New("")
    t = template.Must(t.ParseFS(mytemplateFS, "*"))
}
```